# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: when uploading a file using Python and Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am new to python and flask framework. I have created a simple webpage to upload a file using flask in the current working directory. But when I try to upload a file, it throws PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied. I am using below code:

---

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, request, flash, redirect
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import pathlib
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret'

ALLOWED_EXTENSION = {'csv'}


@app.route("/")
def get_index():
    return render_template('index.html')



@app.route("/upload-holidays", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_holidays():

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.files:
            current_dir = pathlib.Path().absolute()
            file = request.files["file"]
            file.save(current_dir, file.filename)

            return redirect(request.url)

    return render_template('uploadholiday.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

when I try to upload a file, it gives below error:
File "C:\Users\aakas\Downloads\CalendarApp\app.py", line 38, in upload_holidays
file.save(current_dir, file.filename)
File "C:\Users\aakas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 3066, in save
dst = open(dst, "wb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\aakas\Downloads\CalendarApp'

I am using windows 10 and Pycharm community edition.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure, but the issue might come if the file you are trying to upload is currently open in some other app.

Comment: run the app.py as administrator. Open cmd as admin and navigate to your project directory and run the app.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed.

1. used app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER to set the upload folder
2. followed below example exactly as decribed.
   https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Answer (score 0):

even after setting the app.config , it does not work, it gives me the same error, below is my code.

@app.route("/uploadDoc", methods=["GET","POST"])
def uploadDocuments():

```
if request.method == "POST":
    pdfFile = request.files['theFileUploaded']
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = "C:/Users/yassa/OneDrive/Desktop/Yasser/MyProjects/FramworkFlask/app/static/upload"
    pdfFile.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']), pdfFile.filename)
    print("File is uploaded successfully ") 
    return redirect(request.url)

return render_template("admin/dashboard.html")
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34337798)